# Python String formatting - building a table with fixed width columns

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to build a table out of strings of various lengths to look like

```
Bob    | Smith    | UK      | Sales
James  | Hobson   | Ireland | Accounts
```

with all the "|" lined up nicely

have tried using `"{:<10s} | {:<10s} | {:<10s} | {:<10s}".format(fn, ln, loc, div)`
but I get

```
Bob    | Smith    | UK      | Sales
James    | Hobson    | Ireland       | Accounts
```

So the `{:<10s}` seem to be setting padding rather than string length, is there an easy way to fix the length of the strings so the columns line up correctly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Did you apply the same format string to both rows?

Comment: Yes - I'm using a for loop to place values from a nested list in the table

Comment: [Your code works, as you can see on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SturdyIrritatingRefactoring). And `<10` is what you wanted here. Whatever problem you're having, it's in some other part of your code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Do you by chance have any backspace characters `'\b'` in some of the strings? They could trick `format()`.

Comment: Are you maybe displaying this in a proportional font (e.g., by putting it in a tkinter widget rather than printing it to the console), or inserting it into some HTML or some other format that doesn't preserve whitespace, or anything like that?

Comment: There _is_ a problem with this code if any of the strings are longer than 10 characters—for example, if you try it with Joe Reallylonglastname, his last name won't be truncated, so his columns won't line up with anyone else. But that isn't the problem you're showing here, or asking about.

Comment: The plan is to insert into tkinter listbox but have checked the output in the console and get the same result,

plan to set the widths to exceed max length of values for that column

Comment: The code you've shown us doesn't demonstrate the problem you say you're having. If you want us to debug your code, you need to give us a [mcve] that actually has the problem you need debugged, not similar code that already works.

Comment: Abarnart the code I've given with expected and actual outputs clearly demonstrates the issue and does not work. 


my list = [["Bob","Smith","UK","Sales"], ["James","Hobson", "Ireland","Accounts"]]

for i in mylist:
    print("{:<10s} | {:<10s} | {:<10s} | {:<10s}".format(fn, ln, loc, div))

see above for examples of expected and actual outputs.

Comment: The code you just posted in that question has a `SyntaxError` on `my list`, and then a `NameError` on `fn`. But if you fix those problems, it prints the expected output. Again, see [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ImaginarySorrowfulWebpages) for evidence. If you're using Python 2, [it works there as well](https://repl.it/repls/FrostyOffshorePlots). Either this is not your code, or there's something else wrong in some other part of the code, or there's something else wrong with your setup that you're not describing (e.g., your "console" isn't using a fixed-width font or something).

Answer (score -3):

I would fix the positions of the '|' characters in a string of blanks before entering the rest of the data. So, say you want a '|' every set number of index gaps along a string of characters, you could use `insert()` to place '|' at every set number of indexes apart. It might look something like this:

```
string = ""
for i in SizeofString:
    string.append(' ')
for i in NumberofPipesYouWant:
    string.insert('|', indexGap*i)
```

This is just how I would personally do it, I'm not sure if more direct solutions exist.

Comment: There is no `str.insert` method. More generally, strings are not mutable. Appending a single space N times instead of appending N spaces is silly. If this works, it would end up with a string that's `SizeofString + NumberofPipesYouWant` long instead of `SizeofString` long. And you don't even make any attempt to insert the actual data.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been using Python recently and totally forgot subscripting of strings makes way more sense. If you use those instead of append and insert though (again forgot insert is only for lists) though, surely that'd work fine right?

Comment: No. You can't mutate strings through subscripting any more than you can through insert and append; you'll just get a `TypeError` instead of an `AttributeError`. Also, you'd still have all of the other problems—including the fact that your output doesn't even have the desired strings in it, making the whole thing kind of pointless.

Comment: wow, sorry I don't know how I wasn't aware of this. Apologies.